# Parse Date field in multiple formats in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, apply

I have a dataframe field with 480k date records.

The date field has dates with multiple formats: Jan 8, 01-01-2017, dec-08, dec 08, Dec 00, 01/01/2017

Is there a way to parse the field quicker in python?

I tried the following but it takes forever, as it's looping every line

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
for i in range(len(df['Date'])):
    try:
        df['Date'][i] = parse(df['Date'][i])
    except:
        pass
```

I even tried using .apply method. But keep getting an error because of some Dec 00 date format.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
```

Help anyone?

Comment: Did you try `df["Date"].apply(pd.to_datetime)`? The `to_datetime` function is pretty clever and can usually figure out the different formats relatively easily. Not sure what you'd do about Dec 00... What exactly do you expect for values like that? Are all the dates in 2017? What do you want to do in the case there is no year if they aren't? Can you provide a sample of your data with as many of these different formats as possible?

Comment: I presume those are small number of records and I can mutate those dates with today's date.

I'll try `df["Date"].apply(pd.to_datetime)` and revert

Comment: I think your solution almost worked but now I got the following error.
I tried using `df2['Date'] = df1['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)`

but keep getting the error
**OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-11-01 00:00:00**

Comment: Can you give a sample of the dates so we can reproduce it? usually when you want to apply a function over rows, you need the parameter `axis=1` in the apply. Here you are applying it on every column (default value is `axis=0` )